# Logitech install package language shows as numerical

Tags: installation, language

Do I have a corrupt install package for my Logitech cameras? This doesn't happen all of the time, but when installing, the languages show up as numerical instead of the actual language itself. Granted, English is normally the default so I just click on through, but what would be causing this? It is worth noting that I am pulling this from network share which is on Server 2008 and being installed on Windows 7 Professional machines.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a bug in their program. I recall this being featured on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com) a while ago. The installer may be using a system DLL that's an unexpected version; security/functionality patches (or lack thereof) can cause DLLs to operate contrary to what the application developers experienced while they were testing the software. This is common when installers don't ship the system DLLs they use alongside the program. Since I've seen this before, I don't think it's something like a corrupt download; you wouldn't be able to get as far as you have with a corrupt download (usually).

Since it's just the installer, the installed software shouldn't exhibit any negative effects, unless it relies on similar functionality in a similar way and also doesn't ship the expected DLL version with the program...